# Issue when exported a jar for an Android Library project in Android Studio

Tags: android, maven, gradle, jar, aar

Here is the project structure.

+--- Project ':src'
|    +--- Project ':src:sample'
|     \--- Project ':src:mylib'

**mylib** is an Android Library providing with APIs which **sample** depends on. In the **mylib** project, there is an external jar libraries in **/src/mylib/libs/** folder that **mylib** depends on.

When the **sample** depends on the project, which means set the **sample** dependencies as:

> compile project(':src:mylib')

Everything worked fine.

However, i would like to generate a .jar file from **mylib** by renamimg and copying the /mylib/build/intermediates/bundles/classes.jar to /sample/libs/mylib.jar ,and set the **sample** dependencies as:

> compile files('libs/mylib.jar')

It succeed to compile **sample** project and to install the apk on my phone. But the app crashed with a NoClassDefFoundError exception. The classes that app didn't find are the classes in **mylib** AND in the external lib that **mylib** refers.

Is it not the right way to generate the jar file that i used?
If not, then how should i generate a jar file in Android Studio?

Thanks guys.

Comment: How are you creating mylib.jar?

Comment: @RaGe   i used /mylib/build/intermediates/bundles/classes.jar as mylib.jar